# how to mount linuxmint hard drive on linuxmint laptop

Tags: linux-mint, mount, hard-disk

I want to mount linuxmint hard drive using other linuxmint laptop,

this is display of lsblk command on my linuxmint :

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  93,1G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0 368,8G  0 part /home
└─sda6   8:6    0   3,8G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0 298,1G  0 disk 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
but when I try to mount this hard drive with this command

sudo mount /dev/sdb /media/newhd/
```

this process uses a lot of time, about 30 minutes, but no results Note: The hard drive to be mounted containts these partisions : /home, /swap and / , and this size : 300 GB

How to mount this hard drive ?

Comment: The hard drive shows up; that's good. It doesn't seem to have any partitions - what be the output of `fdisk -l`? Aside: those partitons don't have names (as you indicated), they can be mounted to the given mount points.

Answer (score 1):

`/dev/sdb` is not a partition and you can't mount it. You can mount partition with filesystem on it. You can check with `fdisk` command if there is partitions on `sdb`

```
fdisk -l /dev/sdb
```

Comment: this command sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb not responding in a long time

Comment: @sahmada, seems like you have connectivity problem which you should resolve before trying to mount the disk

Comment: how to check if there any conncectivity problem ? thank

Comment: @sahmada, check the cables, sockets, replace cables.

Comment: When I try to run this command fdisk -l /dev/sdb , the result is Cannot open /dev/sdb

Answer (score 0):

Execute **lsblk -fs** to find whether it recognizes partitions with file system.
Otherwise, try **lsblk** command with another Linux distribution, if you experience same scenario that means you have to check your hard disk (maybe).

Comment: This command lsblk --fs produce the same result with lsblk output on my question

Comment: @sahmada exactly, but it indicates us whether the disk is multiple partitioned with file system.